# Does time varying voltage produce electric fields?

Tags: electric-fields

We all know that if we have potential difference between two points in space, then there is an electric field between them but what if I had a region of space which is equipotential initially but has changing voltage due to some reason. So, there is an aspect of potential difference across  time, would this suggest a time varying electric field? or does only spatial variation in voltage produce  electric field.

More precisely speaking, Would time variations in voltage produce time varying electric field? if not, what makes spatial variations special? For example suppose I have a potential function of form $ V(x,y,z,t)$

Comment: Yes, if the voltage between two points is changing then the field is changing...

Comment: it is a voltage difference between two points in time, not two points in space. Does this mean there is an electric field vector across time? that's weird

Comment: No it doesn't... if a bottle has different amounts of water at different points in time does that mean the liquid flowed through time? If there's a planet here at one point in time and not at another point in time, does its gravitational field exist across time? No...

Comment: There must have been some kind of flow in the case you first said. The second one there is no real concept of potential in it. The potential variation across space caused the planets to move, but that's not my question. What if potential was varying with time..

Comment: If the potential is changing then it must have gone somewhere else, since charge is conserved.

Comment: What must have gone somewhere?

Comment: The charges that create the electric field

Comment: I am thinking some like alternating current voltage source rather than fields due to charges. I don't think a charge distribution could create time varying voltage

Comment: AC voltage sources move charges back and forth

Comment: I did not know that is how ac generators worked, I thougth they worked by rotating coils in magnetic fields

Comment: They do, and the rotating coils in magnetic fields cause charges to move around. Also note that moving magnetic fields break Kirchhoff's voltage law.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111187/discussion-between-ddd4c4u-and-user253751).

Answer (score 3):

- Voltage is a term for **potential difference**.
- Two points being equipotential means that they have **the same potential**.

So, by this definition, the voltage between equipotential points **is always zero**.

In general, a voltage does not "cause" the electric field. Rather voltage is a *feature* of the field, or a *measure* of the field. With no field, there's no voltage because there's no tendency for charges to move.